# JAVA: Alignment on GridBagLayout

Tags: java, jtable, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I'm looking for doing an Overlay of Teamspeak3...

The problem is, I can't manage to align a JTable as I want

Screenshot:

http://you-belge.eu/files/2014-03-21_230603.jpg

I want the Table (with 2 names on the screen) to be on Top Left

Here is my code:

```
public void setPanelContent(Object[][] clientList, Object[][] msgList)
{

    JPanel jp_ = new JPanel();

    jp_.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();

    g.gridx = 1;
    //g.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    g.weightx = 1;

    String  title[] = {"A", "B"};
    JTable tableau = new JTable(clientList, title);


    tableau.setTableHeader(null);
    tableau.setRowHeight(20);
    tableau.setShowGrid(false);
    tableau.setEnabled(false);

    // tableau.setOpaque(false);
    ((DefaultTableCellRenderer)tableau.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setOpaque(false);

    tableau.getColumn("A").setMaxWidth(30);
    tableau.getColumn("B").setMinWidth(210);
    // tableau.getColumn("B").setMaxWidth(520);
    tableau.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());

    jp_.add(tableau, g);
    jp_.setBackground(Color.CYAN); // for test

    jp_.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(jp.getWidth(), jp.getHeight()));

    jp.removeAll();
    jp.invalidate();

    jp.add(jp_);
    jp.updateUI();
    this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make a JPanel in the top of your window (BorderLayout.NORTH), a new JPanel inside the JPanel you just created with BorderLayout WEST and then add your JTable insite this last JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want your **table content** to be on Top Left (not your table itself, since it would take all `GridBagLayout` vertical space), you can extend this `JTable` height by adding this:

  ```
  g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
  g.weighty = 1;
  ```
- If you want your **table itself** to be on Top Left, you can use this:

  ```
  g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
  g.weighty = 1;
  ```

Comment: If you want your table itself to be on Top Left, you can use this:        doesn't work :(

Comment: It works for me with your code + the code above. But it may also depend on the size of parent panel (mine takes all window size)